# Expressing a polynomial as the determinant of a matrix of linear forms

Tags: linear-algebra, determinants, noncommutative-algebra, matrix-theory

I have heard that it's a well known result (in theoretical computer science?) that if we have a polynomial $p(t_1,\dots,t_n)$ over $\mathbb Q$, we can find matrices $M_0,\dots,M_n/\mathbb Q$ such that $\det(M_0 + M_1t_1 + \dots M_nt_n) = p(t_1,\dots,t_n)$. (What's a reference for this statement?)

In the case of $n = 1$, this is nothing more than the existence of a companion matrix so we might try and prove the result inductively. Namely, we think of $p(t_1,\dots,t_n)$ as a one variable polynomial over $\mathbb Q[t_2,\dots,t_n]$ and find matrices $P_0,P_1$ denied over this ring such that $\det(P_0 + P_1t_1) = p(t)$.

Now, if there were some "quasi-determinant" operator that let us write a matrix $A(t)$ as the quasi determinant of some other matrix $Q_0 + Q_1t$ and this quasi-determinant satisfied a nice recursivity (I believe it's called hereditary in Gelfond's work?), we could make the above inductive strategy go through. Is there such an operator?

To be very explicit, the question is the following:

Given a matrix $A(t)$ where the entries are polynomials in $\mathbb Q[t]$, can we find matrices/operators $Q_0,Q_1$ and a  nice"quasi-determinant" such that $\mathrm{qdet}(Q_0 + Q_1t) = A(t)$.

An alternative (generalized) way to phrase the question is that we are given a polynomial $p(t)$ over a non-commutative ring and we want to find a description of it as the quasi-determinant of $P_0+P_1t$ for some $P_0,P_1.$

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the sizes of the matrices $M_j$?

Comment: I don't particulary care about the sizes but I heard that the result proves an exponential blowup on the sizes (wrt n).

Comment: This paper seems to contain the desired algorithm https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1804/1804.00145.pdf

Comment: @VladMatei Thank you! I am still interested in the broader question of finding an appropriate quasi-determinant, however.

Comment: Maybe a smaller but more definite question to start with is to characterize which matrices of polynomials can be realized as adjugates of matrices with linear entries, or matrix of $k$-minors ($k$-wedge) of a matrix with linear entries. Of course the size is $\binom{m}{k}\times\binom{n}{k}$, the entries have degree $k$, and the determinant of an adjugate is a pure power, but surely there are more conditions.

Comment: I asked a related question yesterday <https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4060886/on-finding-determinantal-representations-of-polynomials?noredirect=1#comment8389386_4060886>. I have also stumbled on the paper that @VladMatei provided a link to.

Comment: I found a few other references in the meanwhile. http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~helton/BILLSPAPERSscanned/HMV06.pdf and https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/file/index/docid/275615/filename/deter_sym2.pdf for instance. The first 3 slides of this https://services.math.duke.edu/~dasgupta/Transcendence/Transcendence5.pdf also contain a very understandable proof of the claim @Malkoun